# WebKit Threading Violation - While executing instruments commands

Tags: command, webkit, instruments

When we trying to execute the following command, I got the error:

> **WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.**

Command :

```
instruments -w "45aba71d8e1704e30d565036d717f5cccba7047a" -t "Activity Monitor" -D out
```

Kindly help on this error.

Answer (score 0):

That WebKit Threading Violation message sounds important, but it is meaningless. Instruments has been writing that since Xcode 6 beta without any negative impact besides confusing people. Just ignore it.

Try re-running your command, but add the "-v" flag for verbose output. This might give a lot of spam, but the cause of your issues should appear in the last few lines of output.

```
instruments -v -w "45aba71d8e1704e30d565036d717f5cccba7047a" -t "Activity Monitor" -D out
```